# NetSuite Child Custom Record appearing in wrong tab in Item Fulfillment form

Tags: customization, netsuite

I am attempting to create a SuiteBundle in NetSuite that will have a custom record.  That record I need to appear on the itemFulfillment form in my custom tab as a child record (so that it appears as a list/grid).

I am only able to get said Custom Record to appear in the "Custom" tab.

Does anyone know how to make this Record appear in my Custom Tab via the NetSuite interface, or through a SuiteScript?

Thank you.

**Current Location**
[image]

**Desired Location**
[image]

**Already Attempted**
     *To move the custom record from Custom to another subtab, please follow these steps:*

- Go to Setup > Customization > Record Types.
- Select the record type in question.
- Under the Fields tab, click the field where you have "Record is Parent" = Checked.
- On the Edit Custom Field page > Display subtab, look for the "Parent Subtab".
- Assign the name of the tab to where you want to display the custom record sublist or to move it from Custom to another subtab.

The above worked.  Initially I was doing the above but was setting the "Subtab" option.  What needed set was the "Parent Subtab" in the right hand column.  A screenshot has been provided for your benefit.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To move the custom record from Custom to another subtab, please follow these steps:*

- Go to Setup > Customization > Record Types.
- Select the record type in question.
- Under the Fields tab, click the field where you have "Record is Parent" = Checked.
- On the Edit Custom Field page > Display subtab, look for the "Parent Subtab".
- Assign the name of the tab to where you want to display the custom record sublist or to move it from Custom to another subtab.

The above worked.  Initially I was doing the above but was setting the "Subtab" option.  What needed set was the "Parent Subtab" in the right hand column.  A screenshot has been provided for your benefit.
[image]

Comment: After following these steps, you need to apply it to the forms. From the screenshot above, use the Apply to Forms button and apply the new subtab change to any applicable forms.